# Newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 freezes

Tags: freeze

I have an old machine on which I've running Ubuntu for years.
Last week my HDD died and I revamped my machine buying:

- SSD Crucial MX500 (500GB)
- HDD Seagate ST2000DDM008 BARRACUDA (2 TB)

I installed a fresh OS on the SSD (to leverage on speed).

I partitioned the SSD with 30 GB for the OS, 4GB for the swap (equal to the RAM size) and the remaining for /home.

After installation, the OS was incredibly fast and I was super happy.
I installed a LAMP stack (Apache2, Mysql, PHP7.4), ffmpeg, Atom and MEGA (cloud client).

Everything was fine, but suddenly the OS started freezing and a black screen with the following messages appears:

```
- Read-error on swap-device (repeated many times)
- SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data_failed to read block 0x36406d2
- SQUASHFS error: unable to read cache entry [36406d2]
- SQUASHFS error: unable to read page, block 36406d2, size 95f8
- ....
- EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_find_entry:1531: inode #1071059: comm Compositor: reading directory iblock 0
- Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
- EXT4-fs (sda1): I/O error while writing superblock
- ....
- systemd[1]: caught <BUS>, core dump failed (child 10637, code=killed, status=7/BUS).
- systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
- ....
```

I tried rebooting: sooner or later it happens again. I tried reinstalling from scratch, reformatting the SSD, same results...

I'm writing this from a LIVE OS from USB because I can stay in my OS for few minutes before it crashes.

Details from sudo lshw are pasted here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CGkXQRqpX6/

Hope you can help.
Thanks.
Mirko

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did it but it hangs at boot even if I edit grub and put nomodeset... it hangs on purple screen forever :-(... any advice?

Comment: I'm trying replacing the SSD with a new one (waiting for Amazon replacement today) because it might be a memory problem... I'm not full convinced but I'll give it a try... Does anyone have other suggestions in case it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

***SOLVED***
It was my HDD (not the SSD with the OS).
I actually have replaced both but the issue was on the HDD with many bad sectors.
Now everything is working fine and this specific issue is solved.

Thanks.